# Toggle Directories in File Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, file-management

It occurred to me recently that I rarely will use the right pane of Windows File Explorer for manipulating folders and are most often a distraction when working with a folders contents. The left (navigation) pane is where I interact with directories. Could there be a straight-forward way of establishing a toggle to show and hide directories in the right pane? This would be akin to the view menu's toggle to show / hide hidden files.

Comment: No.  Not an option.

Comment: Closest I can think of using built-in capabilities would be to add the `Kind` column to a `Details` view and filter allowing everything but **"Folder"**.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done thru the UI, but there is a set of flags, [FOLDERFLAGS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/ne-shobjidl_core-folderflags), that control certain aspects of displaying the contents of a folder. One of the flags is:

> FWF_NOSUBFOLDERS
> Value: 0x80
> 0x00000080. Do not show subfolders.

You can toggle this flag using **PowerShell** and the shell.application com object as this code domonstrates:

```
@((New-Object -com shell.application).Windows()).ForEach{
   If($_.Document.FolderFlags -band 0x80) {
       $_.Document.FolderFlags = $_.Document.FolderFlags -band ! 0x80 ; $_.Refresh()
   } Else {
       $_.Document.FolderFlags = $_.Document.FolderFlags -bor 0x80 ; $_.Refresh()
   }
}
```

If you copy the above block into a **PowerShell** console window and execute (i.e. press <kbd>enter</kbd>), it will toggle the bit, and thus the visibility of subfolders, *for all open **Explorer** windows*. In the console, pressing <kbd>up arrow</kbd>,<kbd>enter</kbd> will repeat the command and restore the previous state.

- **Important**: The state of this flag is saved with a folder view when the window is closed. So if you close it with folders hidden, they will be hidden the next time you view the folder in **Explorer**. This could cause confusion if others use your computer.

But if this suits your needs and you want easy access to the command, you can make it the target of a shortcut. The text of the command is too long for the  `Create Shortcut` dialog, so you have to create it via code as well:

```
# Edit path and shortcut name as desired
$lnkFilePath    = "$env:UserProfile\Desktop\Toggle subfolder visibility.lnk"
$sc             = (New-Object -com wscript.shell).CreateShortcut($lnkFilePath)
$sc.WindowStyle = 7   # Minimized
$sc.TargetPath  = 'powershell.exe'
$sc.Arguments   = '-NoProfile -Command "&{@((New-Object -com shell.application).Windows()).ForEach{ If($_.Document.FolderFlags -band 0x80) {$_.Document.FolderFlags = $_.Document.FolderFlags -band ! 0x80 ; $_.Refresh()} Else {$_.Document.FolderFlags = $_.Document.FolderFlags -bor 0x80 ; $_.Refresh()}}}"'
$sc.Save()
```